# Copy a folder in same ssrs report server automatically updating new subreport path and shared datasets

Tags: python, c#, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement.It has a folder let say ABC,ABC has data sources, datasets, reports and subreports.
Now after I copy the folder in the same server and name it TESTABC, the data sources are easy to change. But the sub reports and datasets are still pointing to the old path(which is ABC folder). Now changing sub report/shared datasets path is not an easy thing to do especially when there are 100s of SSRS reports. Is there a easy workaround?.Lets say by RS utility or by any programming language, can it be automaatically updated.